# How to add key:value in object iteratively

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am adding key:value pair to productsMap and setting it to productNameMap using setproductNameMap.

However it gives error saying productsMap is not iterable.

What's the correct way to add key:value pair to productNameMap while iterating product array.

```
  const [productNameMap, setproductNameMap] = useState({});
  let productsMap = {}
  products.forEach((product) => { 
      let id = product.id;
      productsMap[id] = product.productName;
  })
  setproductNameMap([...productsMap])
```

Comment: Shouldn't `[...productsMap]` be `{ ...productsMap }`?

Comment: If I am doing   products.forEach((product) => { 

              setproductNameMap({ ...productNameMap,
[product.id]:product.productName  }) })
Is this pushing all the key:value and adding it to productNameMap ?

Comment: The behavior of the spread syntax depends on the context. In an array (`[...myObject]`), it attempts to use the iterable API to enumerate the object and put each item into the destination array. In an object (`{ ...myObject }`), it behaves akin to `Object.assign`, copying the enumerable own properties from one object to another. You are attempting to spread `productsMap` into an array. This means the JavaScript runtime will look for an iterable interface on `productsMap` (which doesn't exist!)

Comment: What does `setproductNameMap` expect? an array of key-value pairs? or an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
setproductNameMap({...productsMap})
```

Comment: If I am doing products.forEach((product) => { setproductNameMap({ ...productNameMap, [product.id]:product.productName }) }) Is this pushing all the key:value and adding it to productNameMap ?

Comment: So the way I have done in the question is the correct way right?

Comment: Yes, I assume that this block will execute inside useEffect or a function.